# Change numbering format for tables in rmarkdown, to whole document instead of per section

Tags: r, r-markdown, caption

I am producing a Word document with tables. This is mycode:

````
---
title: Tables Query
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2: default
---

```{r setup, include= FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE)

```

# Section

Here is Table \@ref(tab:foo)

```{r foo}
knitr::kable( head(mtcars), caption = "a table")
```
    
Here is another table Table \@ref(tab:bar)

```{r bar}
knitr::kable( head(iris), caption = "another table")
```
````

This produces:
[image]

But I just want the tables to be numbered Table 1 and Table 2. If I started an new section with a third table, that would be Table 3.